Need Help Understanding The Different Sizes of KDE plots
I'm new to using ridge plots and would appreciate some help understanding them. I'm trying to compare distributions of data from different advertising campaigns using kde ridge plots. In the visualization, each color represents data from a different campaign.
My question is about the area of the curves. The pink curve at the bottom (with only 400 observations) appears to have a larger area compared to the yellow curve, which has 2,000 observations. The pink campaign has a wider range of data (0 to 40) compared to the yellow campaign (0 to ~27), but I thought that all the areas of each subset of data would be the same because it's measuring the probability that a result would land within the range of values.
Could someone explain why the pink curve might appear larger and what this might indicate about the data or the plot?
I expected all the KDE plots to have the same area, but have different densities. However, the plots show different areas and it doesn't even seem related to the number of observations, and I'm unsure if this reflects something about the data or if it's an issue with the plotting code.
